# Enable HTML Tags in PHPBB

Tags: phpbb

Im trying to find a way to enable HTML Tags in PHPBB (only for administrations).

do you know how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about setting up a PHPBB system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box. You should use custom BBCodes instead. If you really, really insist on HTML tags, you can use the [Enable HTML](http://lithiumstudios.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=535) MOD.

Answer (score 1):

Lately I was busy porting Snitz  2.x based forum to phpbb3 forum.
The main challenge I had to deal with was around HTML support in the post body.
Snitz allowed HTML inside the post body but phpbb3 [forbids](http://www.phpbb.com/community/viewtopic.php?p=4903855) HTML tags inside the post.
Since we have ~40000 posts that many of them contains HTML tags we had to find a solution for this. 
Here it is:
 we used [Enable HTML MOD](http://lithiumstudios.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=535) but we modify it.
The original function:

```
function enable_html($text, $uid)
{
    if (strpos($text, '[html') === false)
    {
        return $text;
    }

    $text = str_replace(array('[html:' . $uid . ']', '[/html:' . $uid . ']'), array('[html]', '[/html]'), $text);

    $text_ary = explode('[html]', $text);
    $text = '';
    foreach ($text_ary as $tmp)
    {
        if (strpos($tmp, '[/html]'))
        {
            $tmp = explode('[/html]', $tmp, 2);
            $text .= htmlspecialchars_decode(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n"), ' ', $tmp[0])) . $tmp[1];
        }
        else
        {
            $text .= $tmp;
        }
    }

    return str_replace(array('[html]', '[/html]'), '', $text);
}
```

was modified to

```
function enable_html($text, $uid)
{
    return htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
}
```

The last step was to give the new permission to the users and we got the HTML rendered as we had it in Snitz.